# Angular universal server error: When using the default fallback, a fallback language must be provided in the config

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have installed angular universal on my app.
Running `npm run build:ssr` - DONE. WORKS.
Running `npm run server:ssr` - DONE.WORKS.

After accessing the server URL (localhost:4000), the page is not fully loaded and the following error is raised on the Terminal:

[image]

Comment: Are you using i18n? And can your show your angular.json file ?

Comment: Already managed to fixed it. Indeed problem with i18n configuration.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i18n Transloco wasn't fully configured on the module file.

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same problem, so I would just like to share my findings for the same.

For me, there were two plausible causes/solutions for it:

- First, in my project's I18N default JSON file that was **en.json**, I was having a problem In the structure of the JSON file.

For example, I had the below mistake. I missed the comma after the second label 'FINISH' :

```
{
"COMMON": {
    "EDIT": "Edit",
    "FINISH": "Finish"
    "QUIT": "Quit",
   }
}
```

So after correcting the structure, the application ran fine without an error.

- Secondly, another cause of the issue could be, at runtime transloco was not able to find the correct label in the selected language, so it looked for a fallback language and it could not even find that in the transloco-root.module.ts so after adding my fallback language, it tried to find the same in the fallback language as specified in the transloco-root.module.ts.

So it found out that label and the issue got resolved.

**BUT** in the second solution provided, you need to have that incorrect label in at least that fallback language's json file in correct format.

I added the fallback language like below:

```
useValue: translocoConfig({
            availableLangs: ['fr', 'en'],
            defaultLang: 'en',
            reRenderOnLangChange: true,
            fallbackLang: 'fr',
            prodMode: environment.production,
            missingHandler: {
                logMissingKey: true
            }
        })
```